# Chrome Text/Input Boxes Broken. Cant use backspace, enter, arrow keys, ctrl shortcuts etc

Tags: google-chrome, keyboard

AS TITLE SAS                                                                                             APOLOGIES FOR CAPS BUT THIS TEXT BOX IS EVEN WORSE FOR SOME REASON                                  I CANNOT USE TAB, ENTER, ARROW KES, CTRL SHORT CUTS IN CHROMES INPUT BOXES                THESE ALL FUNCTION PERFECTL FINE IN WORD, STEAM, INTERNET EXPLORER, ETC>                   SO IT IS NOT A HARDWARE PROBLEM

Comment: Read this page [Chromebook Keyboard Guide](http://www.dell.com/Support/Article/us/en/04/SLN293875) it might help

Comment: Example Turn Caps Lock on or off use Alt + Search [Chromebook keyboard shortcuts](https://support.google.com/chromebook/answer/183101)